# C#/.NET, what to look at?

Tags: c#

I see lots of job ads for C#/.NET programmers, so I thought it could be a good idea to have had a look at it.

After looking at a few tutorials I found nothing really new to me. Just a language with a syntax somewhere between Java and C++ (arguably nicer than both though).

So, what features in particular should I look at? What are some special features? What's the reason that C#/.NET is so large? What are some killer features or perhaps some really evil language gotchas?

Links and code examples are very welcome.

I am using the Mono-implementation on Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compared with Java:

- The "using" statement (try/finally is rarely explicit in C#) (C# 1)
- Delegates as a first class concept (C# 1)
- Properties and events as first class concepts (C# 1)
- User-defined value types (C# 1)
- Operator overloading (use with care!) (C# 1)
- Iterator blocks (C# 2)
- Generics without type erasure (C# 2)
- Anonymous methods (C# 2)
- Partial types (good for code generation) (C# 2)
- Object and collection initializers (C# 3)
- Lambda expressions (C# 3)
- Extension methods (C# 3)
- Expression trees (C# 3)
- Query expressions (aka query comprehensions) (C# 3)
- Anonymous types (mostly used in query expessions) (C# 3)

They're the things I miss from C# when I write in Java, anyway. (That's not an exhaustive list of differences, of course.) Which ones are most important to you is subjective, of course. From a simple "getting things done" point of view the `using` statement is probably the single biggest pragmatic gain, even though it only builds a try/finally block for you.

EDIT: For quick examples of the C# 2 and 3 features, you might want to look at my [Bluffer's Guide to C# 2](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BluffersGuide2.aspx) and the [equivalent for C# 3](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BluffersGuide3.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

The .Net Framework library is more important than the language.

Comment: It's the combination which is important. LINQ would be significantly less useful without extension methods, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Killer feature: super fast Windows programming with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 3.0 [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx) (Language Integrated Query) is worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Exception handling, garbage collection, reflection, a unified type system, machine architecture independence and performance are the main advantages the .NET CLR. The Base Class Libraries are quite comprehensive and comprehensible. Both C# and VB.NET are first class languages for building applications on this platform. Consider learning both.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some of the not so obvious features here

[Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)

And yes, the framework is the largest selling point.